# iTunes home sharing on Windows 7 not showing up on Apple TV 2

Tags: windows-7, itunes, appletv, home-sharing

I am trying to access my iTunes library using an Apple TV 2. On the Apple TV, I logged in using my AppleID, and then I enabled home sharing on iTunes on my main machine running Windows 7.

They are both on the same network, and I can ping my Apple TV from my desktop. I've tried disabling Windows Firewall and restarting the Apple TV, but so far, my library(hosted on the windows rig) does not appear on the Apple TV "Computers" menu.

I'm out of ideas at this point about what could cause this, any thoughts?

Comment: Do you have any security software besides Windows Firewall?  I have to disable my anti-virus when I want to load Media Center on my XBOX 360.  I would imagine the two devices work similar.

Comment: Yes, Windows Security Essentials, I'll try disabling that when I get home.

Comment: Still nothing, I'm not sure what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once fixed all the problems that I was having with iTunes home sharing by doing a repair install on Bonjour.

Procedure on repair install: Go into Control Panel->Programs and Features. Right click on Bonjour and choose "repair".

Answer (score 0):

My TV showed that it was trying to load iTunes from the library but went into an endless loop and was failing to load.  I'm running Win 7 Pro 64 bit. It was a firewall issue. Solved by going to Start>Control Panel>Windows Firewall>Allow a program.....through Windows Firewall.  In the resultant list, check the box(es) for 'iTunes' and click 'OK'.   Worked like magic for me